# How to use RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING encrypt in Java

Tags: java

In Java,how to use  RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING to encrypt? when i use this below ,it shows "javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException:RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding unavailable with RSA".

cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding", provider);

Can you tell me the correct answer?thanks!

Comment: Are you using an Ultimaco HSM? What model?

Comment: yes,I am using Ultimaco HSM. I want to support OAEP padding mode,but it seems not support. what should i do ?Thank you in advance

Comment: You should specify the model, like I asked before, so that we can progress from "seems not support" to a definitive "does not support" or "does support, look for a different problem."

Comment: the provider i am using is "CryptoServerProvider" class,which extends Provider.And it not support OAEP padding

Answer (score 1):

Try without specifying a provider, that is:

```java
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPPadding");
```

If you want to use a specific provider, provide more information about which provider you are using, and what evidence you have that the provider supports OAEP padding.

There is meta-data in the provider itself about the services it provides and their details. We can look into that further if needed, but I think the answer here is simply that this provider doesn't make any provision for OAEP.

Comment: yes, i want to use specific provider.but it report  “ exception message is: No installed provider supports this key: CryptoServerJCE.CryptoServerPublicKey”.

Comment: I am not sure the provider is CryptoServerProvider and i not know much about provider.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party but this could help:

```
private const val ALGORITHM = "RSA"
private const val CIPHER = "RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding"
private const val SHA_256 = "SHA-256"
private const val MGF1 = "MGF1"
private const val PUBLIC_KEY_RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING = "FpMUwRxHsWFXlnAE1iSFC4q3d0bI...." // your public key

val keyBytes: ByteArray = Base64.decode(PUBLIC_KEY_RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", ""), Base64.NO_WRAP)  
val keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(ALGORITHM)
val publicKeySpec = X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes)
val publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec)

val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CIPHER)
val oaepParams = OAEPParameterSpec(SHA_256, MGF1, MGF1ParameterSpec.SHA256, PSource.PSpecified.DEFAULT)
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey, oaepParams)

val encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataToEncrypt.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))

val encryptedStringInUtf8 = Base64.encode(encryptedData, Base64.NO_WRAP).toUtf8String()
```

utf8 helper method:

```
fun ByteArray.toUtf8String() = toString(UTF_8)
```